# _layout default ajax loaded html not getting parsed by jekyll

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I've created a default web _layout for my jekyll site.  Liquid tags get processed as expected in the default.html which is great.  In the excerpt below, the loop and post.url & post.title expand as expected. But I want to load the content into the  with id="page-content-wrapper".  The content that load in the div comes from pages/blog.html.  If I put Liquid directives in that file, jekyll is not processing them, so the content that renders just show the literal "{{ content }}".

How do I get jekyll to process the liquid tags in the pages/blog.html?

[image]

Comment: Did you have a github repository ?

Comment: I've just checked it in: https://github.com/purpleHey/monroeatx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, get it !

Your pages are not generated by jekyll, they are just copied as static files.
In order to generate your pages, your need to add a [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) to them.

#### page/home.html

```
---
layout: null
---
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <h1>Home Page</h1>
        {{ site.name }}
      <p>Content will go here</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3>Sidebar</h3>
      <p>Sidebar content goes here.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will generate the html fragment needed by your ajax call. Do this on every file in `pages` folder.

A little problem come with your permalink setup `permalink: pretty`. With this setup, `pages/home.html` becomes `pages/home/index.html` and your ajax call returns a 404 error.

You can set `permalink: :title` and it will work fine.

Comment: You did indeed get it.  Thank you so much!   I need to read up on how permalink works.  I'm not quite following where the :title is coming from?  Thanks again @David.